# SQL Server exec command works wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, execcommand

I have a stored procedure `spResultFlagUpd` that gets 2 parameters `@p_Code_Sazman` and `@p_Code_Marhale`. This stored procedure must update a column with TRUE and FALSE values

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spResultFlagUpd] 
    @p_Code_Sazman  Nchar(6) = Null,
    @p_Code_Marhale Nchar(6)=Null
AS
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tblResult 
              WHERE Code_Marhale = @p_Code_Marhale  
                AND Code_Sazman = @p_Code_Sazman 
                AND Confirmed = 1 AND SendFile = 1 AND MakeFileFlag = 1)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE tblResult 
        SET MakeFileFlag = 0
        WHERE Code_Marhale = @p_Code_Marhale  
          AND Code_Sazman = @p_Code_Sazman
    END
```

When I run

```
exec spResultFlagUpd @p_Code_Marhale='000060', @p_Code_Sazman='000021'
```

it does not update the table.

But when I run the update code as a SQL query, it works correctly.

When I write the code pure like

```
   update tblResult 
    set MakeFileFlag=0
    where Code_Marhale=@p_Code_Marhale  and Code_Sazman=@p_Code_Sazman
```

it works correctly

Comment: Check whether this query returns any result `SELECT * FROM tblResult WHERE  Code_Marhale = '000060' AND Code_Sazman = '000021' AND Confirmed = 1 AND SendFile = 1 AND MakeFileFlag = 1`

Comment: yes it returns 1 unique record

Comment: even when i right click on sp and execute sp from this window with values , it works correctly too @Prdp

Comment: Add sample data of `tblResult` table. We can check its working or not

Comment: how can i add data ? i added degsin mode of tables image to question

Comment: just add sample data of these columns `Code_Marhale, Code_Sazman, Confirmed, SendFile, MakeFileFlag` no need to all the data just the required data which falls under your current scenario

Comment: Code_Marhale='000021', Code_Sazman='000060', Confirmed=1, SendFile=1, MakeFileFlag=1

Comment: You could move your whole _exists_ to the end of the UPDATE query. I suggest you use SQL Profiler or the debugger in SSMS to observe the sp executing line by line

Comment: @Mina - add sample data like it is showed in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39114757/update-a-column-with-sequence-numbers-without-using-row-number-in-sql-server

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i am using SQl Profiler now

Comment: Good luck just make sure you use event `SP:StmtCompleted`. Is there any reason you don't just include all logic in a single update statement? The `IF` seems unnecessary (and the added complexity is contributing to your bug). Basically something is not matching the way you think it is

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid
i deleted that IF EXCISTS statement completely but the problem excists

Comment: Try using `VARCHAR` instead of `CHAR` for your parameter data types. `CHAR` retains padding. Are all the data types identical throughout? i.e. what data type is the column `Code_Marhale`?

Answer (score -1):

The exists statement is working. The problem is the update. Your code is being compiled before the if is being run. So, the error occurs during the compile stage.

You can fix this by using dynamic SQL:

```
 IF EXISTS (select * from tblResult where Code_Marhale=@p_Code_Marhale  and Code_Sazman=@p_Code_Sazman and Confirmed=1 and SendFile=1 and MakeFileFlag=1)
begin
  exec sp_execute_sql N'update tblResult set MakeFileFlag=0 where Code_Marhale=@p_Code_Marhale  and Code_Sazman=@p_Code_Sazman';
End;
```

try this code with your own modifications

Comment: i tried it whitout IF EXISTS statement , again it did not update

Comment: @Ralis - Even OP's procedure does not throw any error

Comment: its working great on my side i have run this sp using my table and columns it is working there is something you are missing @mina

Comment: @Mina - As Rails said your procedure should as expected you are missing something

Comment: i am confused completely

Comment: facebook is filtered in iran

Comment: i am sure there is a minor mistake at your side that is annoying you...

Comment: @Ralis - You are not supposed to ask those info from OP. Whatever it takes try to fix it here only

Comment: i cant find that mistake , can anyone help me to fix it ?

Comment: @Prdp i know but i think she is newbie at sql she is missing something definitely.

Comment: there seems to be a mismatch between your procedure name and the log it generates: no insertion will ever be done by update statements.

Comment: @Mina check your query by placing a breakpoint there if it is going into the begin end section

Comment: @Ralis....... the stored procedure creation is not conditionally dropping out the update statement. That's incorrect. If you script the stored procedure back out after creation you'll find that it includes the update no matter what.

Comment: @Ralis 
The program '[1276] [SQL] (local): (local)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: @Mina that doesn't look like a SSMS error code - how are you running this?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it is the result of execution with breakpoint. there is no error

Comment: Ah I see. So it ran the update line - no need really to debug now that there is only one line in the stored proc. Did you try VARCHAR instead as I suggested in the other comment thread?

Comment: i dont need VARCHAR , i need 6characters only @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Did you try it? Do you know the difference between `VARCHAR` and `CHAR`? What sample data are you running it with? It would help if you posted a sample call